# adding max_len to a 2D array to become 3D array

Tags: python, reshape, word2vec

I have text features with dimension 2D (1096,100)
I need to combine my text feature with my audio feature where the text feature needs to be in 3D.
Shape should be (1096, 50, 100), where 50 is max_seq_len.

How should i do this?

```
def get_average_word2vec(tokens_list, vector, generate_missing=False, k=100):
    if len(tokens_list)<1:
        return np.zeros(k)
    if generate_missing:
        vectorized = [vector[word] if word in vector else np.random.rand(k) for word in tokens_list]
    else:
        vectorized = [vector[word] if word in vector else np.zeros(k) for word in tokens_list]
    length = len(vectorized)
    summed = np.sum(vectorized, axis=0)
    averaged = np.divide(summed, length)
    return averaged

def get_word2vec_embeddings(vectors, clean_text, generate_missing=False):
    embeddings = clean_text['tokens'].apply(lambda x: get_average_word2vec(x, vectors, 
                                                                                generate_missing=generate_missing))
    return list(embeddings)
    
text_embeddings = get_word2vec_embeddings (word2vec, df, generate_missing=True)
text_embeddings = np.asarray(text_embeddings)
text_embeddings.shape
(1096, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey. After few days of study, i found out that i can get 3 dimensional features from text via Bert. Some references are (just to share);

[Bert to the rescue!](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-to-the-rescue-17671379687f) [Sentiment analysis with Bert](https://curiousily.com/posts/sentiment-analysis-with-bert-and-hugging-face-using-pytorch-and-python/)